# Unable to read configurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use ConfiguartionProperties to read properties from application.prop files. But I am getting NullPointerException  because at the time of initiating the bean the properties are not read properly from application.prop file.

```
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "httpool")
    public class ClientHttpPoolConfig {

        private Integer maxPerRoute;
        private Integer maxTotal;
        private Integer connectionRequestTimeout;
        private Integer connectTimeout;
        private Integer socketTimeout;

        @Bean
        public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClntConnMger() {
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager result = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            result.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxPerRoute);  // maxPerRoute is null.
            result.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);
            return result;
        }
}
```

Comment: To confirm , the properties file is named application.properties or application.prop ?

Comment: application.properties

Comment: Can you share `application.properties` content? To be honest I didn't try this combination yet, I will and I'll let you know. Are the values loaded without `poolingHttpClntConnMger()`. Maybe `@PostConstruct` is what you need.

Comment: It worked for me - properties are available in method, maybe problem with prefix as in first answer... Optionally you can remove prefix to test (prefix is optional, only Idea says differently).

Comment: @Betlista can u please give yours solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified as much as I could, so I'm using very simple bean:

## StringWrapper

```
package betlista.springTests.beanInConfiguration;

/** Represents a very simple Bean */
public class StringWrapper {

    private String name;

    public StringWrapper(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

There is nothing special in configuration class too...

## Config

```
package betlista.springTests.beanInConfiguration;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Config {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Bean
    public StringWrapper getStringWrapper() {
        return new StringWrapper(name);
    }

}
```

and finally application

```
package betlista.springTests.beanInConfiguration;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    StringWrapper stringWrapper;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        LOG.info("stringWrapper.name: {}", stringWrapper.getName());
    }

}
```

Just for completeness

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>springTests-beanInConfiguration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## Prefix

Pretty much same works with `@ConfigurationProperties("my")` and `my.name=Betlista` in property file.

All available in GitHub: https://github.com/Betlista/SpringTests/tree/master/BeanInConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

in your application.properties files, parameters should be as follow:

```
httpool.max-per-route=//here  your Integer value
httpool.max-total=//here  your Integer value
httpool.connection-requestTimeout=//here  your Integer value
httpool.connect-timeout=//here  your Integer value
httpool.socket-timeout=//here  your Integer value
```

EDITED:
and you must write this annotation to your Main class

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        ClientHttpPoolConfig.class
})
```